# python scrape a div with more than one class name using response.css

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, classname

I'm new to Scrapy and working on a scrapy project.

I want to scrape a div with more than one class name as below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 available-columns inner-available trans-fade-in"><div>
```

Here is my scripy (the def parse) :

```
def parse(self, response):
    for flight in response.css('div.col-xs-12 available-columns inner-available trans-fade-in'):
        yield {
            'price': flight.css('span.w-bold::text').extract_first(),
        }
```

And the output is empty.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
for flight in response.css('div.col-xs-12.available-columns.inner-available.trans-fade-in')
```

In case of multiple classes, you can separate them by dot(.)

Comment: Can I see the url? You can only use one of the available classes like `available-columns` or `trans-fade-in` whatever meets your needs

Comment: I have tried that. I used one of the classes but still no output. https://www.alibaba.ir/flights/SYZ-THR?adult=1&child=0&infant=0&step=results&departing=1397-2-30  (I want to get the green numbers)

Comment: The problem is the website is sending `ajax` request calling a different API and using JS to manipulate the data. Here I found this endpoint using the browser's network that have the information you need https://ws.alibaba.ir/api/v1/flights/domestic/available/MTc4NzYzNDE0LTAtNjM2NjE4MzUxNzI5Mjc2ODE3LTE=                                                                Just parse these `JSON`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That was helpful in general.